# Jquery scroll is not picking changed variable value to be sent to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, scroll

I am not a regular programmer and has learnt whatever programming I know by google or by asking things here from Stackoverflow.

I am trying to create a ajax function which will fetch feeds from database on scrolling based on selected parameter. User can select either to select public feeds or personal feeds. His chosen value is updated in hidden text field. Code follows as below.

[image]

```
//feed menu switch between personal and public  
$('.menu_selection').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
    increaseArea: '20%' // optional
});         
$("body").on("ifChecked",".menu_selection",function(){
    var feed_menu_selected = $(this).val();             
    $("#feed_menu_selected").val(feed_menu_selected);       
    $("#member_menu_area").html(loader);
    IndexFeederLoader('0','0','0'); 
});
```

Now this is function which is fetching records where `group_no` is the record set being fetched, `total_m_group` is total number of records, `feed_menu_selected` is the choice between public or private.

```
function IndexFeederLoader(group_no,total_m_group,movie_shown){

var feed_menu_selected = $("#feed_menu_selected").val();

$.ajax({            
    url: '../index-feeds.php',
    type: "POST", 
    dataType:"text", 
    data: 'feed_menu_selected='+feed_menu_selected+'&group_no='+group_no+'&movie_shown='+movie_shown,               
    cache: false, 
    async: false, 
    success: function(data){
        if(group_no == 0)
            {
                $("#member_menu_area").html(data);
                //when personal is checked and not signed in
                var notsigned = $(data).filter('#notsigned').text();
                if( notsigned !== '')
                    {
                        $("#SignInForPersonal").show(); 
                    }
            }
        else
            {
                $("#member_menu_area").append(data);
            }

        total_m_group = $("#total_page_no").text();                     
        $("#total_m_group").remove(); // removing extra     

        movie_shown = $("#movie_shown").text();
        $("#movie_shown").remove(); // removing extra

    }, 
    complete: function(){                       
        $(window).on("scroll",function(){   
            var closeToBottom = ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 500);
            var AtBottom = ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height());            
            if (closeToBottom || AtBottom)  
                {       
                    if( total_m_group != 0 )
                        {
                            if( group_no < total_m_group )
                                {   
                                    group_no++;
                                    IndexFeederLoader(group_no,total_m_group,movie_shown); // group_no is not changing
                                }
                        }   
                    else
                        {
                            group_no = 0;
                        }
                }   
        });
    },              
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){                
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

}

Now the problem. If I do not switch between public and personal, everything goes well and I get records in order of group_no set. But when I select personal and then come back to private, it does not work giving feeds from start but from where it has left. It seems like `group_no`is not changing.

Thanks for reading. It would be great if anyone can help me pls.

Answer (score 0):

First problem i can see - in your `$.ajax` in `complete` callback you attach new event on `$(window)` each time it's executed. So when you execute 2 times it'll be 2 events called and so on. Change logic to attaching event once and changing context of it if it's needed.

Second - don't mix up variable types. You're executing IndexFeederLoader passing Strings, but using Numbers

[JsFiddle to understand what's happening](https://jsfiddle.net/hgdxtpb5/)

So, like you're doing - i'm attaching an event over and over again, passing `context` variable. Try pressing button - it will fire a lot of different events with it's own context eventually. That is what probably causing bugs in your code.

Comment: Thanks for being patient and pointing out the problem clearly. But request you further if you can help me as how can I correct the above function. I am getting helpless searching continuously through google about the right code sample to achieve what I need.